# EclipseLink doesnt show the SQL invoked on SELECT query.in Log file

Tags: jsp, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, jpql

This is the JPQL instruction, every employe can submit several tickets, so i'm going to select all the tickets related to an employee.

```
private static final String JPQL_SELECT_PAR_EMP = "SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE t.id_employe = :id_employe";
private static final String PARAM_EMP           = "id_employe";
```

This is the DAO method, "findtickets":

```
public List<Ticket> trouverTickets( int id_employe ) throws DAOException {

    List<Ticket> lticket;
    Query requete = em.createQuery(JPQL_SELECT_PAR_EMP);
    requete.setParameter(PARAM_EMP, id_employe);
    try {

        lticket = requete.getResultList();

    } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
        return null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
    return lticket;
}
```

This is the method that gathers the parameter id_employe through the request object.

```
public List<Ticket> recupererTickets(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    List<Ticket> liste;
    int id = getId(request);
    if(id!=0){
        liste = ticketDao.trouverTickets(id);
    }else liste=null;
    return liste;
}
```

And finally the servlet.
if the list containing the tickets is empty, it sends you to a JSP page that is empty.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    CreationTicketForm ticketform = new CreationTicketForm(ticketDao);
    List<Ticket> lticket = ticketform.recupererTickets(request);

    boolean resultat;
    if(lticket.isEmpty())
    {
        //resultat="Vous n'avez soumit aucun ticket";
        resultat = false;
        request.setAttribute("resultat", resultat);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ListeTickets2.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else{
        //String VUE = "/ListeTickets.jsp";
        resultat=true;
        request.setAttribute("resultat", resultat);
        request.setAttribute("lticket", lticket);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

else it sends you to this JSP page which iterates the list and shows details about your tickets.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${resultat==false}">
        <p>Vous n'avez pas de ticket</p>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Sujet</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Priorite</th>
                <th>ID Ticket</th>
                <th>Etat</th>
                <th>Date Soumise</th>
                <th>Action</th>                   
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${lticket }" var="ticket" varStatus="boucle">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${ ticket.sujet }"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${ ticket.description }"/></td>
                 <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.priorite == 1 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Faible"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.priorite == 2 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Moyenne"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.priorite == 3 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Haute"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <td><c:out value="Priorite non-défini"/></td>
                    </c:otherwise>
                 </c:choose>

                 <td><c:out value="${ ticket.id_ticket }"/></td>
                 <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.etat == 1 }">
                        <td><c:out value="En attente de prise en charge"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.etat == 2 }">
                        <td><c:out value="En attente de votre validation"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.etat == 3 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Cloturé"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <td><c:out value="Etat du ticket non-défini"/></td>
                    </c:otherwise>
                 </c:choose>
                 <td><c:out value="${ ticket.date_envoi }"/></td>
                 <td><button class="btnSelect">Selectionner</button></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        </c:otherwise>     
        </c:choose>
```

There's no stacktrace, the JSP page just shows the first line containing each row's name, this assuming that the parameters used to get a result through JPQL is valid.

**EDIT:** There goes the ticket entity

```
package projet.helpdesk.beans;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Tickets")
public class Ticket {

private int priorite;
private int etat;
private int id_employe;
private int id_technicien;
private String sujet; 
private String description;
private Timestamp date_envoi;
private Date date_fermeture;
@Id
private int id_ticket; 

public int getId_ticket() {
    return id_ticket;
}
public void setId_ticket(int id_ticket) {
    this.id_ticket = id_ticket;
}
public int getId_employe() {
    return id_employe;
}
public void setId_employe(int id_employe) {
    this.id_employe = id_employe;
}
public int getEtat() {
    return etat;
}
public void setEtat(int etat) {
    this.etat = etat;
}
public int getId_technicien() {
    return id_technicien;
}
public void setId_technicien(int id_technicien) {
    this.id_technicien = id_technicien;
}
public String getSujet() {
    return sujet;
}
public void setSujet(String sujet) {
    this.sujet = sujet;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Date getDate_envoi() {
    return date_envoi;
}
public void setDate_envoi(Timestamp date_envoi) {
    this.date_envoi = date_envoi;
}
public int getPriorite() {
    return priorite;
}
public void setPriorite(int priorite) {
    this.priorite = priorite;
}
public Date getDate_fermeture() {
    return date_fermeture;
}
public void setDate_fermeture(Date date_fermeture) {
    this.date_fermeture = date_fermeture;
}
}
```

**EDIT:** Persistence.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="bdd_helpdesk_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/bonecp_resource</jta-data-source>
    <class>projet.helpdesk.beans.Utilisateur</class>    
    <class>projet.helpdesk.beans.Ticket</class> 
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this is the only SQL query i can see in the logs file, and it is related to authentication.

```
2017-05-01T15:38:22.863+0100|Précis: SELECT id_emp, agence, date_inscr, departement, email, mdp, nom, poste, prenom, type FROM Utilisateur WHERE (email = ?) bind => [UNID@UNID.COM]
```

Comment: where are the entities? where is the FIELD called "id_employe" in class Ticket? what SQL is invoked when you run the query?

Comment: @NeilStockton I added the ticket entity, and the JPQL instruction is mentioned at the top.
The condition "!list.isEmpty" is satisfied so the list is'nt empty, otherwise it would redirect you to an empty JSP page, but when iterating the list in the JSP page, it doesn't show its content, adding xml persistence code.

Comment: @NeilStockton checked the logs, couldn't find any SQL query invoked, even if in case it's a successfull query that inserts a row in the DB that is visible afterward through sql command line.

Comment: A query doesnt "insert" a row. Any JPA provider will have the SQL visible in the log, for the purposes of debugging. We'll ignore why you have no relations in that class and are storing "id"s of related objects only.

Comment: @NeilStockton So there's no SELECT Query i could find related to the tickets, only a SELECT query that is related to the authentication.

`2017-05-01T15:38:22.863+0100|Précis: SELECT id_emp, agence, date_inscr, departement, email, mdp, nom, poste, prenom, type FROM Utilisateur WHERE (email = ?)
 bind => [UNID@UNID.COM]`

Comment: Is your question how to turn on logging, or why you are not getting any results?  You have to turn on logging for any JPA provider to start logging.  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging You don't snow how you obtain the EntityManager, so I'm guessing it is container managed - you'll have to configure your container log settings to get at the JPA logging unless you change EclipseLink to use the DefaultLogger

Comment: I actually fixed the issue, i had a problem sending the employe's id it was sending null.